# É válido votar em uma pergunta "pendente"?

Tags: debate

Já percebi em algumas oportunidades que perguntas marcadas como **`[pendente]`** continuam "abertas" para serem votadas (*upvote/downvote*).

Venho pensando **SE DEVEMOS** continuar fazendo isso e enxergo pontos a favor e contra:

**sim**:

- pra quem vota é vantagem pois (normalmente) está marcando corretamente uma pergunta como não útil (o que rende medalhas no *SO*)
- se eu considero a pergunta ruim, voto contra; é uma ação totalmente independente da sinalização e do fechamento

**não**:

- quem fez a pergunta perde pontuação, mesmo ela já encerrada
- particularmente quando voto contra e comento algo que possa ser melhorado, acompanho a pergunta por um tempo pra remover o voto, caso a edição seja aceitável; se ela já está fechada, não faria tanto sentido o voto (assim como o comentário)

Comment: Existe várias perguntas fechadas como duplicatas que são boas e merecem votos positivos.

Comment: pensei nisso e acho válido, por isso explicitei na pergunta que a dúvida era sobre as pendentes (que são fechadas "por serem ruins")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O voto e o fechamento de fato são coisas independentes. Uma pergunta fechada pode ser boa ou ruim. Então votos continuam podendo ser dados, inclusive porque ela pode ser reaberta.

É raro o caso que eu acho que uma pergunta fechada merece um positivo, mas acontece. É comum eu achar uma pergunta fechada merecer negativo, mas eu diria que a maioria que eu fecho eu não negativo.

O negativo é se a pergunta tem baixa qualidade, não que ela tem um problema que impede de aceitarmos. Se a pergunta é fechada e negativada será removida depois de um tempo, o que é bom para limpar as coisas ruins do site. Se a pergunta é só fechada não será removida. Então tem que analisar o caso específico, ela deve ficar no site mesmo fechada ou deve ser removida?

Então faz sentido votar na pergunta mesmo ela fechada.